# How to call a terraform module in another GitHub repository

Tags: github

I want to reference terraform module in https://github.com/identity/terraform-aws-github-oidc-provider repository from my repo identity/identity-iam-global-terraform to create some resources in AWS.Please how will source parameter look like? both repo belong to the same organization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference: https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/sources#github

I've used this successfully in some of my config;

```
module "idc-provider" {
  source = "git@github.com:identity/terraform-aws-github-oidc-provider"
}
```

OR if you have tags on your commits (versions):

```
    module "idc-provider" {
      source = "git@github.com:identity/terraform-aws-github-oidc-provider.git?ref=v1.0.0"
}
```